# C# Selenium: Redirect and get stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to overcome this certain situation I've encounterred.

Error :

```
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

The piece of the code that resulted in the following error is :-

```
 webDriver.Url = "https://www.xzy.com/groups/profile/list";

        Console.WriteLine("Thread Checkpoint 1");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ICollection<IWebElement> links = webDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href*='https://www.xzy.com/grouplink/url/groups/']"));

        foreach (IWebElement link in links)
        {       
                Console.WriteLine(link.Text.ToString());
                link.Click();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                webDriver.Url = "https://www.xzy.com/groups/profile/list";
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully navigated");
                webDriver.Navigate().Refresh();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple! When you navigate to a new page you get a whole new DOM, So you cannot click the links that were stored in the collection that you called `links`.